# How to rename using rapidminer?

Tags: rapidminer

"The first data set has a car name attribute, whereas the second data set has a
name attribute. name should be renamed to car name".This is my question.How to solve this? a value for the parameter new name must be specified is the error i am getting.

Answer (score 2):

The `Rename` operator takes two parameters; one is the existing attribute name and the other is the new name you want the attribute to be renamed to.